# javascript - how to validate dynamic add input with multiple same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I try to do form validation with javascript or jquery (but don't use jquery validate plugin) for the multiple inputs that has same name and added dynamic input.
I want all the input is required to fill.
but it's not work.  How could I do to validate it in this case??

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
</script>
<script>
function chk_null()
{

    $('input[name="mytext[]"]').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "")
    {
        alert("Please Fill");
        return false;
    }
});
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form action="new2.php" method="post" onsubmit="return chk_null();">
    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button type="button" class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text"  name="mytext[]"></div>
    <div><input type="text"  name="mytext[]"></div>

</div>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest an alternative. Set your button type as "button" and if your check is ok, then submit the form. [Here the example.](https://jsfiddle.net/amkcmnsb/)

```
<form action="new2.php" method="post">
.
.
.
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="chk_null();">
.
.
.
function chk_null() {
   var allFilled=true;
   $('input[name="mytext[]"]').each(function() {
       if ($(this).val() == "") {
           alert("Please Fill");
           allFilled = false;
       }
   });
   if (allFilled) $('form').submit();
}
```

Comment: sorry but is it possible to make it return only 1 alert message?

Comment: @doflamingo Sure, add `return false;` after `allFilled = false;`. Here the updated example: https://jsfiddle.net/amkcmnsb/1/

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me this is working. If you try changing your script slightly it might clear up what is happening:

```
function chk_null()
{
    var isValid = true;
    $('input[name="mytext[]"]').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "")
        {
          alert("Please Fill");
          isValid = false;
        }
    });
    return isValid;
}
```

If you run this with four fields and 1 is filled in, you will get 3 alerts. Perhaps you were thrown off by only getting one alert if there are multiple fields not filled in, but that was because you were immediately returning false.